# Uber API for Real time tracking

Tags: uber-api

I want to know whether I can use uber api to track the ride real-time basis. I have found uber help suggest the following:

*"Can I see the path a rider took during a trip?"
This feature is only available for ongoing UberPOOL rides. The request details return a set of waypoints (incl. pickup and dropoff locations) for each UberPOOL ride. This information is not accessible in the history but just during the ride.*

So does it mean it is not applicable to other types of ride? Please let me know. It will be great if someone can suggest exact API endpoint for tracking the ride on a real-time basis.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-map-get  and https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-current-get   Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It can be checked for any type of ride that you've requested

> The Ride Request endpoint allows retrieving the status of an ongoing or completed trip that was **created by your app**

You have a few different options

1. [Ride Request - Map API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-map-get)
2. [Ride Request - Current API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-current-get)
3. [Ride Request - Details API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get)